# Default.aspx via code?

Tags: web-template, module, remote-provisioning

Would it be possible and recommended to add a custom Default.aspx (when no publishing nor wiki front page are enabled) via code (remote provisioning) vs adding it via a Module declaratively? are there other than performance drawbacks of adding it via code (maintenance etc)?

Comment: As a note, if there is no good or bad recommendations either way for this answer, then I suggest that you do whatever you do for other files added to the site - that is, keep things consistent.